# Count of days that have at least 1 job open using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, count

I have a MS Access table that has a list of jobs that were executed (Job ID, StartDate, EndDate) I need to find the count of days in a specified date range (e.g. between 1st Jan and 30 Jun) that a user selects using textboxes that have at least 1 job open ie between `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I have some experience with VBA and with SQL (not very good with grouping).

Could anyone assist me with a suggestion of  how I could get this count?

```
JobID|  StartDate|  EndDate  
1142|   03-Jan-14|  04-Feb-14|  
1143|   13-Mar-14|  18-May-14|  
1144|   03-Jan-14|  29-Jan-14|   
1145|   20-Jan-14|  13-Apr-14|     
1146|   03-Jan-14|  07-Jan-14|
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar table?  That would seem like the only feasible way of doing this in Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a calendar table as suggested in the comments and add a button called cmdCountJobDays to your form.
    The below code will check all possible dates in the selected date range against the job dates. A bit clunky but it will get you there :-)

```
Private Sub cmdCountJobDays_Click()  
    Dim StartDate as Date  
    Dim EndDate as Date     
    StartDate =  me.txtYourStartDateTextBox
    EndDate =  me.txtYourEndDateTextBox
    SQLGetJobCountPeriod = SQLGetJobCountPeriod & "Select CalendarDate from tblCalendarDates where CalendarDate >=" & cdbl(StartDate)
        SQLGetJobCountPeriod = SQLGetJobCountPeriod & " and CalendarDate <= " & cdbl(EndDate)
        Set dateschecked = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLGetJobCountPeriod)
            If dateschecked.EOF = False Then
                dateschecked.MoveFirst
                    CountOpenJobDays = 0
                    CountAllDays = 0
                    Do While dateschecked.EOF = False
                        CurrentCheckDate = CDbl(dateschecked.Fields("CalendarDate"))
                            SQLJobDates = "Select StartDate, EndDateDate from jobdetails "
                            Set Jobdates = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLJobDates)
                                If Jobdates.EOF = False Then
                                    Jobdates.MoveFirst
                                    Do While Jobdates.EOF = False
                                        Jobstartdate = CDbl(Jobdates.Fields("StartDate"))
                                        Jobenddate = CDbl(Jobdates.Fields("EndDate"))
                                        If (CurrentCheckDate > Jobstartdate - 1) And (CurrentCheckDate < Jobenddate + 1) Then
                                            CountJobOpen = CountJobOpen + 1
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        Jobdates.MoveNext
                                    Loop
                                End If
                        CountAllDays = CountAllDays + 1
                        dateschecked.MoveNext
                    Loop
            End If
    msgbox CountJobOpen
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I go about creating a calendar table? What information should be contained?

Comment: You could create a list of daily dates in Excel and then import this file into your MS Access DB as a table and voila! you have a calendar table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is there a SQL solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The count is using a datediff function.

```
datediff(dd,startdate, enddate)
```

"dd" tells it to find days, start date would be 1/03/2014, and end date would be 2/04/2014 as an example for your first line

Comment: hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I know you are only trying to help, but your syntax isn't even valid MS Access syntax. There is no "dd" in Access. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

Comment: In your title it says using SQL so was trying to give you SQL code. My bad. In your link you just use the "d" then